# Sound plays when screen is turned off

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I connect my computer to a screen via a HDMI port, via which I listen to music through my headset. I notice that, when the screen is turned off, e.g. after a few inactive minutes, the speakers start to play. This is sort of annoying. If I am away for a while, then people around my desk will be disturbed by this behavior. Is there any way to solve it? The expected behavior should be the sound keeps going through the HDMI port after the screen is off.

---

```
$ pacmd list-sink-inputs
2 sink input(s) available.
    index: 129
        driver: <protocol-native.c>
        flags: START_CORKED 
        state: RUNNING
        sink: 68 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        muted: no
        current latency: 31.25 ms
        requested latency: 18.75 ms
        sample spec: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        resample method: copy
        module: 12
        client: 34 <Firefox>
        properties:
                media.name = "AudioCallbackDriver"
                application.name = "Firefox"
                native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
                native-protocol.version = "32"
                application.process.id = "29311"
                application.process.user = "hu"
                application.process.host = "hu-N85-N87-HJ-HJ1-HK1"
                application.process.binary = "firefox"
                application.language = "en_CA.UTF-8"
                window.x11.display = ":0"
                application.process.machine_id = "0e2fd9e6cece498f8d4d706d8fb7dc80"
                application.process.session_id = "5"
                application.icon_name = "firefox"
                module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:Firefox"
    index: 766
        driver: <protocol-native.c>
        flags: START_CORKED 
        state: RUNNING
        sink: 68 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
        volume: front-left: 52016 /  79% / -6.02 dB,   front-right: 52016 /  79% / -6.02 dB
                balance 0.00
        muted: no
        current latency: 116.17 ms
        requested latency: 75.00 ms
        sample spec: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        resample method: copy
        module: 12
        client: 34 <Firefox>
        properties:
                media.name = "AudioStream"
                application.name = "Firefox"
                native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
                native-protocol.version = "32"
                application.process.id = "29311"
                application.process.user = "hu"
                application.process.host = "hu-N85-N87-HJ-HJ1-HK1"
                application.process.binary = "firefox"
                application.language = "en_CA.UTF-8"
                window.x11.display = ":0"
                application.process.machine_id = "0e2fd9e6cece498f8d4d706d8fb7dc80"
                application.process.session_id = "5"
                application.icon_name = "firefox"
                module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:Firefox"
```

Comment: Can you run the cmd `pacmd list-sink-inputs` during that situaltion?

Comment: I updated with the output.

Comment: the sound comes from firefox. But sadly more can I not say.

Comment: yeah i don't have to run that command to know that...